# Помогите составить SQL запрос для такой задачи

Tags: sql

Есть таблица `order`.

```
id, customerId, createdAt
```

Пример данных:

```
ID: 5, customerId: 111, createdAt: 2022-07-01T10:44:22.000Z,
```

Как мне получить `customerId` всех пользователей, что совершили с `2022-06-01` по `2022-07-01` более 50 покупок. То есть, будет более 50 таких записей в таблице, где `customerId` равен `111`, в этом временном промежутке.

с DISTINCT по `customerId`, чтобы убрать дубли.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как это сделать в MS SQL Server. Вы можете изменить SQL для любой базы данных.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, customerId INT, createdAt datetime);
INSERT @tbl (customerId, createdAt) VALUES
(1, GETDATE()),
(1, GETDATE()),
(2, GETDATE()),
(2, GETDATE()),
(2, GETDATE()),
(2, GETDATE());
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

DECLARE @start_date DATE = '2020-01-01'
    , @end_date DATE = '2024-12-31';

SELECT customerId, COUNT(*) AS [Counter]
FROM @tbl
WHERE createdAt >= @start_date AND createdAt <= @end_date
GROUP BY customerId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2; -- 50
```